# Error I'm getting is 'FileNotFoundError '

Tags: python, pandas

I was going systematically and I was getting an error. I have saved this file in the provided file path however it is still giving an eroor.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path="D:/ds/ecoli"
conc = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Comment: The error I am getting is FileNotFoundError: File b'D:/ds/ecoli' does not exist

Comment: You're supposed to pass a fully qualified path including the file name itself: `conc = pd.read_csv(path + 'my.csv')` what you passed was a path to a file named `ecoli` with no extension. Vote to close as this is a typo